# Protobuf define a field that can be either int or float

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, dynamic-typing, proto

I would like to define a field that can be either int of float. Is this possible in Google's Protobuf? Is there another way that can be done? I need this of python, where types can be inferred in run-time.

For example I would like something like that:

```
message Vector {
    repeated (float or int32) value=1;
}
```

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Would an oneof do? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof

Comment: Thanks, yes that could possibly work, somethiing like this..?

message VectorValue {    
    oneof value {
        int32 int_value = 1;
        float float_value = 2;
    }
}

message Vector {
    repeated VectorValue value=1;
}

But, I wonder if there is any other more simple way..

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Then every client that interacts with the protocol will need to have a separate `if` condition for int vs. float. Also note that float can represent all integers up to 2²⁴ accurately.